# Is it Possible to Make a Desktop Application (With GUI) using only C?

Tags: c, visual-studio, desktop-application

So I've looked around for a few days now and the resources seem pretty scarce ... I get that it's quicker to use a dedicated language for this (like C++), but I'm still curious about where I could learn to do it with only C.

[This tutorial seemed kind of promising](http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/main/), but I thought surely there must be some more out ... does anyone know of any?

Comment: Plain old C? No libraries? Just `<stdio.h>` and other headers defined by the Standard?

Comment: C++ is not the `dedicated` language for this. Even quicker you will write GUI in C# (for example using Winows forms).

Comment: Yes, you can do it. In fact, using Visual Studio (near any flavor) if you select a new project, then select Visual C++ (don't let the name fool you), then Win32, you're going to be offered two options: Win32 Console Application, and Win32 Project. The *latter* of those will skeleton out basically the boiler plate for what you seem to be asking. It may look a little odd at first, and I strongly suggest getting the *fifth* edition (or earlier) of Petzold's "Programming Windows", which, at one time, was the de'facto goto reference to millions of up-and-coming Windows app authors.

Comment: @pmg that was the original thought, but I just discovered GTK and so will see where that goes

Comment: @WhozCraig cool that sounds good I'll definitely look into it

Comment: Yes, you should use [GTK](http://gtk.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible.

Sure you'll need platform headers, like `<windows.h>` but those are C headers.

But it is not a very good idea, even as learning exercise.

C is too low level language for desktop applications. Windows Drivers are normally written in C, as well as console apps, but GUI objects are better with object-oriented language, which can provide object-oriented interface for Windows objects.

Comment: Ok that makes sense I suppose ... but why isn't it a good learning exercise?

Comment: Yeah, I can only reinforce this.  I would only use an OO language and an IDE with a form designer.

Comment: @Kai ..because it will drive you insane, very quickly:)